# Servlet exception deploying maven enterprise project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish

I get this error when I try to access to the servlet named `BookingServlet`

Grave:   exception caught
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/it.volaconnoi_VolaConNoi_webapp-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/it.volaconnoi_VolaConNoi_webapp-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/BookingBean!it.volaconnoi.logic.BookingBeanInterface' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: it.volaconnoi_VolaConNoi_webapp-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT]

and this is the screenshot

[image]

The project is deployed correctly but I don't understand why I get this error. Do you any suggest?

As you may see the booking servlet is in its place

[image]

EDIT

```
BookingBeanInterface bookingBean = lookupBookingBeanLocal();


private BookingBeanInterface lookupBookingBeanLocal() {
        try {
            Context c = new InitialContext();
            return (BookingBeanInterface) c.lookup("java:global/it.volaconnoi_volaconnoi-webapp-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/it.volaconnoi_volaconnoi-webapp-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/BookingBean!it.volaconnoi.logic.BookingBeanInterface");
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
            throw new RuntimeException(ne);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I understood the problem but I need your help to resolve it... the problem depend from the fact I execute the code above to call an ejb stateful

Answer (score 0):

Really not enough description, you should describe where is your class `BookingBean` is located, and by what means it registered in JNDI. But if we assume that registration is correct, you could try to lookup it using following string:

```
c.lookup("java:app/BookingBean/it.volaconnoi.logic.BookingBeanInterface");
```

See more description here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html